# Limsup and Liminf in Construction of Lebesgue Measure in Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am reading Rudin's construction of the Lebesgue Measure in 'Real and Complex Analysis' (Theorem 2.20).

In this theorem Rudin defines $P_n$ to be the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}^k$ which are integral multiples of $2^{-n}$ and defines;

$$\Lambda_n f = 2^{-nk}\sum_{x\in P_n} f(x)$$

where $f$ is a continuous complex function with compact support. He then assumes that the function is real and the support lies in an open k-cell $W$.

I am trying to verify the statement;

> the upper and lower limits of $\{\Lambda_n f\}$ differ by at most $\epsilon \text{vol}(W)$

I have thought about this for a while and it seems quite intuitive to me, but I want to prove it rigorously.

I use the inequality which he proves;

$$\Lambda_N g=\Lambda_n g \leq \Lambda_n f \leq \Lambda_n h = \Lambda_N h$$

where $g$ and $h$ are functions with support in $W$ such that $g$ and $h$ are constant on each box belonging to $\Omega_N$ (the set of all $2^{-N}$ boxes), $g\leq f \leq h$ and $h-g<\epsilon$.

Here was my attempt;

$$\begin{aligned}&\limsup_{n\to\infty} \Lambda_n f - \liminf_{n\to\infty} \Lambda_n f\\&= \limsup_{n\to\infty} \Lambda_n f + \limsup_{n\to\infty} (-\Lambda_n f) \\&\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \Lambda_n h + \limsup_{n\to\infty} (-\Lambda_n g) \end{aligned}$$

If I could show at this point that

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \Lambda_n h + \limsup_{n\to\infty} (-\Lambda_n g) \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \Lambda_n(h-g)$$

then using the expression for $\Lambda_n(h-g)$ it is obvious to me that this is less than $\epsilon \cdot \text{vol}(W)$ since it is equal to $\epsilon$ times the limit of a Riemann sum of the number one over $W$. I can see why $\lim_{n\to\infty} \Lambda_n f$ is the limit of a Riemann sum.

I couldn't show that the above inequality holds however so this is what I tried, using $\Lambda_n g = \Lambda_N g$ if $n>N$ and similarly for $h$;

$$\begin{aligned}&\limsup_{n\to\infty} \Lambda_n f - \liminf_{n\to\infty} \Lambda_n f\\&\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \Lambda_n h + \limsup_{n\to\infty} (-\Lambda_n g)\\& = \limsup_{n\to\infty} (\Lambda_N h)+\limsup_{n\to\infty}(-\Lambda_N g) \\ &= \Lambda_N h - \Lambda_N g \\&= \Lambda_N(h-g)\\&\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \Lambda_n(h-g)\\&=  \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left \{ 2^{-nk} \sum_{x\in P_n \cap W} [h(x)-g(x)] \right \} \\&\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left \{ 2^{-nk} \sum_{x\in P_n \cap W} \epsilon \right \} \\ &= \epsilon \cdot \text{vol}(W) \end{aligned}$$

but I have some doubts and am unsure if this is valid.

If anyone could comment on whether my reasoning is valid or point me to some other questions/answers that address this question that would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I'm now a bit more confident in my approach. I realised intuitively the reason $\Lambda_n g=\Lambda_N g$ for $n>N$ is that $g$ is piecewise constant so once the partition/interval sizes are small enough further dividing the partitions should not change the Riemann sum.

Comment: Without loss of generality assume that $\operatorname{supp}|(f)\subset[-b,b]^k=I$. It seems that what you have is the Riemann sum of $f$ over $I$. As $f$ in continuous and supported in  $I$, the integral of $f$ over $\mathbb{R}^k$ is the same as the integral over $I$.

Comment: Rudin states explicitly later that his approach is designed to avoid reference to the Riemann integral. The claim in the op's edit is correct, which justifies his/her proof.